# How to filter (blank) in Excel Pivot VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to filter (blank) columns in VBA. There will be times when there will be no (blank) columns but there will also be times that there will be (blank) columns. Here's what I got so far:

```
    Dim PItem as PivotItem
    .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = True
    For Each PItem In .PivotItems
        If PItem.Name <> "(blank)" Then
            PItem.Visible = True
        End If
     Next
```

However this fails if there are no (blank) columns. Please help

UPDATE: Sorry I forgot to include that this is a pivot table

Comment: `(blank)` is generally just the visual representation of empty cell `""`, have you tried that?

Comment: Why don't you include line2 within the "for next", using a second "if then" or "else " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Guard against `PivotItems(name)` error, when name not in PivotItems

- For missing Values/Names, use the string "`(blank)`" [as identified by the OP].

**To make the name "`(blank)`" not visibility:**

Use Error ([Microsoft Answers: Test if item in PivotItems](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/test-for-existence-of-a-Pivotitem-in-a-pivotitems/b66734f9-2704-43b1-93ae-52ab661a87ab))

```
On Error Resume Next
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
On Error GoTo 0
```

-OR-

Use a Loop

```
Dim PItem as PivotItem
For Each PItem In .PivotItems
    If PItem.Name = "(blank)" Then
        PItem.Visible = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

**To Set every item's visibility based on their name**
Use a Loop

```
Dim PItem as PivotItem
For Each PItem In .PivotItems
    PItem.Visible =  PItem.Name <> "(blank)"
Next
```

Comment: This absolutely works with missing, blank, empty string values. Your assessment in the comment under the OP was not accurate, the value of a missing/blank is "`(blank)`" and **NOT** the empty string `""`.  Please try the code for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, @TedD., works perfectly! You saved me hours of work! :)

Comment: Ana, you're welcome. Perhaps @MátéJuhász will reconsider the down vote.